# Calculus partial derivatives problem; how can I prove this relationship?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Can anyone help me with this proof, I've attached my working out so far:

*Show that:* $\phi =Ae^{-\frac{kt}{2}}sin(pt)cos(qx)$ satisfies the equation

$$\frac{\partial \phi^{2}}{\partial x^2}=\frac{1}{c^2}\left ( \frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial t^2} + k \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}\right )$$

provided that $p^{2}=c^{2}q^{2}-\frac{k^{2}}{4}$.

Working out so far (click to magnify):

[image]

Comment: Even with magnification that's a pain in the ass to read.

Comment: I have no problem with that link on my side...?

Comment: It looks like you did not use the product rule when you took the derivatives so some of the partials are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the product rule when computing $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$, you've only taken the deriviative of one term containing $t$.

Answer (score 0):

By chain rule, $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial{t}} = A\cos(qx)\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}(e^{\frac{-kt}{2}}\sin(pt))=A\cos(qx)\big[\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}(e^{\frac{-kt}{2}})\sin(pt)+e^{\frac{-kt}{2}}\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}(\sin(pt)\big]$.

So, $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t} = A\cos{(qx)}e^{\frac{-kt}{2}}\Big[-\frac{k}{2}\sin(pt)+p\cos(pt)\Big]$.

By a similar application of chain rule to this result, you have $\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial{t^2}}$.

Retry, using this facts.

Comment: Thanks, going through it now is that A definitely negative at the start of the last line?

Comment: Oh, I just noticed a mistake in my calculations. $A$ is positive and $p sin(pt)$ should be replaced with $p cos(pt)$ (as is now). I have edited my answer to do these corrections.